# Django unicode with recursive ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, unicode, foreign-keys

So i have a class - Deparmtent.

each Department (except for the biggest) has a bigger Department which it belongs to.

my class looks like this :

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overDep = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to make def `__unicode__` which will return the department name than '-' and than the biger Department name so in result it could look like : 'BUSS-AEPR-ERPG' as ERPG is the biggest Department which includes AEPR which includes BUSS.

I have no idea how to do it, I tried to return : 'self.name+"-"+self.overDep.name' but it gives an AttributeError - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

So please show me how to do it right, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    if self.overDep:
        return u'%s - %s' % (str(self.overDep), self.name)
    else:
        return self.name
```

Comment: DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /admin/faxim/department/

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <Department: [Bad Unicode data]> (<class 'faxim.models.Department'>)


      Well that`s what I got after trying your solution.

Comment: @TomerI look at the edited answer, try adding the u char before string

Comment: Thanks man you\`e the best !.. Can you explain why my option did not work and your`s do work?

Comment: @tomerl you're welcome, my option works because I've first checked that overDep column is filled (otherwise trying to get the name property you get the AttributeError - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'), and also I've implemented the recursion needed here by calling `str(self.overDep)`. In fact casting the object to string implies a call to the the same __unicode__ function, and the recursion occurs untill the overDep called has no parent and just returns its name.

You can accept the answer if it was actually useful to you.